# How do I delete Mask data blocks in Masking tab

Tags: masking

Blender noob coming from Houdini.

How do I delete these mask data blocks in the masking tab? They seem to keep getting created but I have no idea how to delete or clean them up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the number of users to zero by clicking the X next to the data block in the masking tab and then "clean up all data blocks" from the file menu (top right).

Comment: Why was my comment edited?

Comment: I asked for more clarification as this system seems pretty awful

Comment: I mean if you're going to edit it can it not be something useful?

Comment: You should SHIFT + Left click the X icon to set the user number to 0. Alternatively click on the shield icon to remove Fake User. The system is particular to Blender, you'll find many, many discussions about its pros and cons over the internet if you want more information about why it exists. I guess your comment has been edited because it didn't add much to your answer, which should stay concise and to the point. (Site policy). I have added an answer which may be more straightforward for your need. Cheers

Comment: Thank you Gorgious! That works. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a an *Outliner* editor, go to *Blender File* context, unfold the *Masks* subpanel, Left click on the first entry you want to delete, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Left click on the last entry you want to delete, Right click > Delete.

[image]